# Expecting a popup upon closing the browser

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python

I am expecting a pop-up upon closing the browser. For example, when you are shopping and you have items in cart and in the middle of the checkout process, you wanted to close the tab/browser, at that time the site should give you a pop-up asking "Are you sure you want to leave?" or something similar!

I'm using Selenium with python.

When I do, `driver.close()` it just closes the browser. It does not give any pop up.

Is there any other method that I can use?

Comment: Instead of closing the browser all together, try using Key commands which simulate browser closing - Ctrl + W shortcut is one way. Or can you give me an example, where you observe this.

Comment: It is depends on site I think , Have you seen it for any site and in any browser?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a JavaScript popup handler for your test before closing the browser.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get("http://abc.com")
```

try:

```
alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()  # If you don't want to accept it it's alert.dismiss()
browser.close()
```

else:

```
print("No popup")
```